# Google Script - Bamboo HR API

Tags: api, authentication, google-apps-script, bamboo, urlfetch

How do i connect Bamboo Hr with google sheets?

```js
function myFunction() { 
  var url = "https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/company/v1/employees/directory";
  var apiKey = "API KEY";
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch( url, { "headers":{ "TRN-Api-Key":apiKey } } ); 
  var content = res.getContentText(); 
  Logger.log(res);
  Logger.log(content);
}
```

Also, how do you authenticate with email and password in this?

https://documentation.bamboohr.com/docs/getting-started

Comment: Hey Suhas, welcome to Stackoverflow. I have provided an answer, kindly let me know whether that works for you. Cheers

Comment: How to get the employee directory all data including birthday, date of birth, and hire date fields?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the docs:

> Most browsers and tools can accept a URL such as:
>
> https://{API Key}:x@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/{subdomain}/v1/employees/directory

You simply will have to create a URL that suits that format. See below:

```js
function myFunction() { 
  var url = "https://%s:x@api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/company/v1/employees/directory";
  var apiKey = "API KEY";
  var requestUrl = Utilities.format(url, apiKey);
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch( requestUrl, { "headers":{ "TRN-Api-Key": apiKey } } ); 
  var content = res.getContentText(); 
  Logger.log(res);
  Logger.log(content);
}
```

Otherwise, you can use the `Authorization` header. You can easily do that with the following code:

```js
function myFunction() { 
  var url = "https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/company/v1/employees/directory";
  var apiKey = "API KEY";
  var authHeader = "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(apiKey + ":x");
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch( url, { "headers":{ "TRN-Api-Key": apiKey, "Authorization": authHeader } } ); 
  var content = res.getContentText(); 
  Logger.log(res);
  Logger.log(content);
}
```

Either of these options should work. Please consider as well whether you need the "TRN-Api-Key" header, as I have not found any reference to it in the Bamboo HR reference documents.

Comment: How to get the employee directory all data including birthday, date of birth, and hire date fields?